# Split and transfer into respective columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data frame as below.Unsorted and variable number of characters.

```
+-------+
| Items |
+-------+
| X,Y,Z |
+-------+
| Z,X,Y |
+-------+
|  Z,X  |
+-------+
|   Y   |
+-------+
```

I want to split each entry by `,` and feed into respective columns. Number `1` if the value is available and `0` if not available.

My desired output as below

```
+-------+---+---+---+
| Items | X | Y | Z |
+-------+---+---+---+
| X,Y,Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+-------+---+---+---+
| Z,X,Y | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|  Z,X  | 1 | 0 | 1 |
+-------+---+---+---+
|   Y   | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+---+
```

I know how to split the dataframe by `df['Items'].str.split(',')`. But feeding into respective column is the issue. coz' the items are unsorted. see row 1 and 2. same, but unsorted.

please guide me how should I approach to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `pd.Series.str.get_dummies()`

```
df=df.join(df.Items.str.get_dummies(','))
```

Comment: just curios to know, is there a reverse `get_dummies()` method? for example , in the same example above, if the columns `X,Y,Z` are given with `1 and 0` values. then to combine back to the string? reverse back. (ofcource sorting is not an issue in this case)

Comment: @Tommy s= df.Items.str.get_dummies(','); s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]

Comment: woow. awesome. Thank you. you're a genius and pandas is very powerful..

Comment: how can we learn these kinds of advance techniques? any recommended materials, videos, etc

Comment: @TommyTo it is hard to find a document ~ you can check some courses in coursera~

Comment: sure, will check coursera, thank you for your time. cheers